# How to close MessageDialog in SWT from non UI thread?

Tags: eclipse, swt

I have progress dialog running in UI thread. Another thread is running in the backround and when finished must close the progress dialog.

On the UI thread:

```
messageDialog.open(); // synchronous
```

I have tried this from backround thread:

```
UiUtils.syncExec(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                   dialog.close();
            }
       });
```

but the close event is not handled by UI thread.

Comment: Is it possible to post a simple running/executable code as I am able to close a **shell** when my worker thread finishes.

Comment: Does UiUtils post to the SWT Display?

Comment: What does `UiUtils.syncExec` do? Try just `Display.getDefault().syncExec(...)`. See the reference: [Display.syncExec](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display.html).